60's or 70's book about a planet of only women
Trying to find a 60's or 70's book about a planet of only women.  Many searches have been done to no avail.

Can you tell us anything more about the plot or characters? Were the women human or aliens, for example? And did any male characters feature in the story? If so, in what capacity?

More than one of these exist.

@Spencer - Women? Or planets? Or books?

@Valorum Exactly.

Wonder Woman came from a planet of only females, right?

Wife remembers reading this as an adolescent.  She looks forward to seeing how she perceives it now.  We also ordered a book I remember from my adolescence called the Singing Cave (published in the same year), also looking forward to seeing how I perceive it now (both of us reading these about 50 years later).  If this comment violates any of the site rules, please feel free to delete it.

Don't put the answer (found by someone else) in your question. If you want to show the book cover you can edit the answer.

Others include Houston, Houston, Do You Read and When It Changed by Joanna Russ, and War against the Yukks by Keith Laumer.

Virgin Planet (1959) by Poul Anderson, perhaps? From the linked review

Three centuries ago a shipload of female castaways was swept by the
trepidation vortex into the Delta Capitis Lupi system. They had no
hope of rescue or escape. Rather than accept that their fledgling
community was doomed to dwindle and vanish as the castaways aged and
died, the ship’s doctor turned to induced parthenogenesis to ensure
the survival of the human race on this alien world. Three centuries
later, the Doctors still have a monopoly on the reproductive
technology required to people Atlantis.


This was a question from my wife.  She is so excited about getting an answer, thank you very much!

Great! I'm very glad to help
